# SQL Server 2012 - ASP.NET - VB.NET - Insert Data into database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, insert

I am trying to insert data to a db table using SQL statement with VB.NET.

This is my code:

Registration.aspx:

```
Imports dbConnect
Imports System.Data.SqlClient


Partial Class Registration
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnRegister_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegister.Click

        register()


    End Sub


    Public Sub register()



        Dim Username As String = txtUsername.ToString
        Dim Surname As String = txtSurname.ToString
        Dim Password As String = txtPassword.ToString
        Dim Name As String = txtName.ToString
        Dim Address1 As String = txtAddress1.ToString
        Dim Address2 As String = txtAddress2.ToString
        Dim City As String = txtCity.ToString
        Dim Email As String = txtEmail.ToString
        Dim Country As String = drpCountry.ToString
        Dim DOB As Date = calDOB.SelectedDate
        Dim Occupation As String = txtOccupation.ToString
        Dim WorkLocation As String = txtWorkLocation.ToString
        Dim Age As Integer = "20"

        Dim ProjectManager As String = "test"
        Dim TeamLeader As String = "test"
        Dim TeamLeaderID As Integer = 1
        Dim ProjectManagerID As Integer = 1

        Dim RegistrationDate As Date = Today
        Dim ContractType As String = "test"
        Dim ContractDuration As Integer = 6
        Dim Department As String = "test"
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim registerSQL As SqlCommand
        Dim sqlComm As String

        sqlComm = "INSERT INTO users(Username, Password, Name, Surname, Address1, Address2, City, Country, date_of_birth, age, Occupation, department, work_location, project_manager,team_leader, team_leader_id, project_manager_id, date_registration, contract_type, contract_duration) VALUES('" + Username + "','" + Password + "','" + Name + "','" + Surname + "','" + Address1 + "','" + Address2 + "','" + City + "','" + Country + "','" + DOB + "','" + Age + "','" + Occupation + "','" + Department + "','" + WorkLocation + "','" + ProjectManager + "','" + TeamLeader + "','" + TeamLeaderID + "','" + ProjectManager + "','" + RegistrationDate + "','" + ContractType + "','" + ContractDuration + "')"

        conn.Open()

        registerSQL = New SqlCommand(sqlComm, conn)

        registerSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()


    End Sub



End Class
```

This is my database 'users' table:

[image: Users Table]

I am getting this error message:

```
Error   1   Operator '+' is not defined for types 'Double' and 'Date'.  C:\Users\Brian\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite1\Registration.aspx.vb  51  19  WebSite1(1)
```

Can anyone tell me whats going on ?

Comment: Use parameterized queries and NEVER construct your query string like that, FYI - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i

Answer (score 3):

As Lloyd pointed out, [parameterize your queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx). E.g. (shortened for readability)

```
sqlComm = "INSERT INTO users(Username, Password, Name) VALUES(@Username, @Password, @Name)"
registerSQL = New SqlCommand(sqlComm, conn)
registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username)
registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password)
registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name)
```

But to answer your question, use `&` instead of `+` to concatenate a String.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you a starting point

```
  sqlComm = "INSERT INTO users(Username, Password, Name, Surname, Address1, Address2, " + 
            "City, Country, date_of_birth, age, Occupation, department, work_location, " + 
            "project_manager,team_leader, team_leader_id, project_manager_id, " + 
            "date_registration, contract_type, contract_duration) " + 
            "VALUES(@p1, @p2,@p3,@p4,@p5,@p6,@p7,@p8,@p9,@p10,@p11,@p12,@p13,@p14,@p15," +
            "@p16,@p17,@p18,@p19,@p20)"
    conn.Open()
    registerSQL = New SqlCommand(sqlComm, conn)
    registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Username)
    ..... 
    registerSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

And when the value to pass to the AddWithValue method is not a string, try to convert to the correct datatype expected by the database field.

```
    registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", Convert.ToDateTime(DOB))
```

In this way you don't have to worry about parsing strings with double quotes or automatic conversion of strings to date, moreover, you don't have problems with Sql Injection attacks

Comment: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Comment: Can't say, I have assumed that DOB is a string representing a date, could you check with the debugger what is the real value of DOB at the point of the conversion (not to mention the other date at parameter @p18)